# CRM 2011 : Plugin to create duplicate records

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

i created a simple plugin to create a duplicate record that refers to the parent record.

Here is my code

```
        var pluginExecutionContext = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;

        IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

        abc= pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;

        if (pluginExecutionContext.Depth == 1)
        {
            Guid abcId = abc.Id;
            Entity abcCopy = new Entity("mcg_abc");


            if (abc.Attributes.Contains("mcg_abccategoryoptioncode"))
            {
                abcCopy.Attributes["mcg_abccategoryoptioncode"] = abc.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("mcg_abccategoryoptioncode");
            }

            if (abc.Attributes.Contains("mcg_effectivedate"))
            {
                abcCopy.Attributes["mcg_effectivedate"] = isp.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("mcg_effectivedate");
            }

            if (abc.Attributes.Contains("mcg_startdate"))
            {
                abcCopy.Attributes["mcg_startdate"] = isp.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("mcg_startdate");
            }

            if (abc.Attributes.Contains("mcg_enddate"))
            {
                abcCopy.Attributes["mcg_enddate"] = isp.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("mcg_enddate");
            }

            if (abc.Attributes.Contains("mcg_amendeddate"))
            {
                abcCopy.Attributes["mcg_amendeddate"] = isp.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("mcg_amendeddate");
            }
             if ((abc.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("mcg_abccategoryoptioncode").Value) == 803870001)
                {
              //Some more fields;     

                }
               else
               {
              //Some more fields;    
               }
            // SOme more fields;
            abcCopy.Attributes["mcg_parentabc"] = new EntityReference("mcg_abc", abc.Id);
             service.Create(abcCopy);
```

}

Now the problem is all the fields before the below check are getting copied

```
 if ((abc.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("mcg_abccategoryoptioncode").Value) == 803870001)
```

However fields after this check are not getting copied.

Please if anybody could suggest what mistake i have made.

Comment: Are you saying the `if` section is executing, rather than the `else` (or vis-a-versa) or are you saying that the `//Some more Fields;` isn't actually setting anything?

Answer (score 0):

In case you take field from Target - this field was updated on a client side. In case field was not updated - it would not be in Target. You should use Images to get values of unchanged fields.

Answer (score 0):

The field must be empty so a exception may arise. Try to use the plugin image or change your code to this way:

```
if (abc.Attributes.Contains("mcg_abccategoryoptioncode")){
  if ((abc.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("mcg_abccategoryoptioncode").Value) == 803870001)
....
```